# how do i make Activity intentFilter action dynamic from strings.xml

Tags: android, action, intentfilter, android-productflavors

I'm using different product flavours, and opening an Activity through intentFilter whose action is predefined as shown below.

```html
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.package.name.MyAction"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

For opening this activity I'm using :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.package.name.MyAction");
startActivity(intent);
```

Now, if my device have both product flavour apk, a chooser is coming for some device to open which activity app, for some devices it show a error `no app found to perform the action`.

As soon as I uninstall one app, and keep only one app in my device everything works fine.

One solution I thought to overcome is, to make the action constant as `Intent intent = new Intent("com.package.name.MyAction");
context.startActivity(intent);` dynamic. But I'm not sure how can I do this.

Im AndroidManifest, it should be something as:

```html
<action android:name="com.package.name.MyAction"+getString(R.string.product_name)/>
```

This is the part where I'm unable to get the string in `AndroidMaifest`.

For opening the activity I have done:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.package.name.MyAction"+getString(R.string.product_name));
startActivity(intent);
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Just curious to know, why can't you maintain separate `manifest` files for each flavors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` (app), config your flavors like this:

```
    productFlavors {
        first {
            // ...
            manifestPlaceholders = [action: "com.package.name.ActionA"]
        }

        second {
            // ...
            manifestPlaceholders = [action: "com.package.name.ActionB"]
        }
    }
```

Then place the value of placeholder in `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="${action}"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In order to get the placeholder to open the activity, just get it through `BuildConfig`:

```
    String yourAction = BuildConfig.action;
    // start your intent here
```

Comment: Yeah this will do. More info at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables

Comment: @nhp this really helped thanks, However I find @kavin link more useful, so I have used that, since in my flavour I was already using applicationId, so instead adding a `action` field, I used that `applicationId`.
Thanks @kavin and @nhp appreciated your help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you out. Roger that the combination of application and other placeholders too ^^